# Why does Bash always add a newline when expanding here strings?

Tags: bash, shell, newline, stdin

Having read the following description of this feature of Bash (excerpt from the man page):

> **Here Strings**
>
> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
> <<<word
> ```
>
> The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

I expected that the interpretation of here strings is that Bash simply passes the contents of a variable directly on a command's standard input, unmodified. Following this logic, the lines `[1]` and `[2]` below would be effectively equivalent.

```
[1]~$ printf foo | cat - <(echo end)
fooend
[2]~$ cat - <(echo end) <<<foo
foo
end
```

However, Bash added a newline when “expanding” a string, something I didn't anticipate. This happens even when a variable ends with newline itself:

```
[3]~$ printf "foo\n" | cat - <(echo end)
foo
end
[4]~$ cat - <(echo end) <<<foo$'\n'
foo

end
```

Tested in 4.2.25 and 4.3.30.

So my question is: is this behavior specified anywhere in Bash docs? Can I depend on it in scripts?

Comment: Newlines are *required* for a file or stream to be valid text-file content in UNIX. `read` fails (in the has-a-nonzero-exit-status sense) absent them; multiple standard UNIX tools have undefined behavior when newlines on input are missing. You absolutely won't see this change in future releases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Haven't thought about that, thanks. However, not every tool works on text files (`wc -c`, `md5sum`), and so in general command's stdin is not *required* to be a valid text file. Also Bash doesn't always add a newline (see examples in the post), and so this argument alone doesn't explain much.

Comment: Chepner's historical background for herestrings as syntactic sugar for one-line heredocs is spot on.

Comment: ...that said, I don't see any of the examples in the question countering my explanation. In the case of `printf`, you're requesting explicit control, which is a very distinct case; in the case of `cat`, bash has no control over what a subcommand outputs, and *no visibility into it either* -- so it couldn't see if there was already a trailing newline to add a missing one even if that were desired!

Comment: The bottom line, though: A change here would break enough 3rd-party code in things that are actually used day-to-day that it absolutely wouldn't make it past alpha phase.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy However, Bash is the one expanding `<<<foo$'\n'` and it adds the second trailing newline regardless of the fact that the string already has one. Don't you think that disagrees with your explanation?

Comment: I don't see how, no. What part of my explanation requires the behavior to be conditional?

Comment: Hmm. I suppose one could argue that the behavior of adding an extra newline *even when one is already present* isn't as compatibility-breaking were it to disappear, and could go away in the future. I think that's a fair argument. If you want to be 100% explicit about ensuring that you get an extra newline even in that case, use a proper multiline heredoc.

Comment: `bash` doesn't look at the value of the here string before deciding to add a newline; it just adds it. This makes it consistent with how here documents expand.

Comment: It doesn't make it consistent with how here documents expand, since here documents already contain newlines - nothing is added here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not definitive, but I believe a here string is intended to be equivalent to a single-line here document, so that

```
cat <<< foo
```

and

```
cat <<EOF
foo
EOF
```

are equivalent. Since a here document always ends with a newline, so should the here string.

---

Consider this simple use case for a here string:

```
IFS=: read foo bar <<< "a:b"
# foo=a
# bar=b
```

If a newline weren't provided by the here string, the exit status of `read` would be 1. (See with `printf "foo" | { read; echo $?; }` vs `printf "foo\n" | { read; echo $?; }`.)

Comment: Thank you! This seems like the most plausible explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is: is this behavior specified anywhere in Bash docs?
>   Can I depend on it in scripts?

The specification has now been added to the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings):

> The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to
>   the command on its standard input (or file descriptor *n* if *n* is
>   specified).