# Number of lines from command output and variable differs, wc, bash

Tags: bash, wc

Why `wc` reports different number of lines when it consumes direct command output and when when the output is stored in variable?

```
$ virsh list --all | grep -P -- '(-|(\d+))\s+\S+\s+\S+'
$ var=$(virsh list --all | grep -P -- '(-|(\d+))\s+\S+\s+\S+')
$ wc -l <<< "${var}"
1
$ virsh list --all | grep -P -- '(-|(\d+))\s+\S+\s+\S+' | wc -l
0
$ echo "x${var}x"
xx
$ cat <<< ${var}

$
```

1., 4. invocation suggests that the command (`virsh | grep`) outputs nothing. 5. invocation suggests that the variable contains empty string. However for some reason wc reports one line in invoaction 3.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in [Here string](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html) redirection (triple angle bracket). It may add new line:

```
$ a=''
$ xxd <<< "$a"
00000000: 0a
```

Comment: There's also a discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33245568/why-does-bash-always-add-a-newline-when-expanding-here-strings).